# Find a decent alternative to forced explicit type annotation?

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-annotation

While testing some code that I recently created i figured that some passages are not compiling without explicit type annotation. I tried to minimize the problem in the following code snippet:

```
case class Base[E,S](al:Set[E],sts:Set[MidState[S]],ss:MidState[S],
                            d:Map[(MidState[S],E),MidState[S]],aS:Set[MidState[S]])

case class Edge[E,S](state_1: MidState[S],l:E ,state_2: MidState[S])

sealed trait MidState[S] extends BaseState[S]

sealed case class State[S](l:S)
  extends MidState[S]

case object FailureState extends MidState[Nothing]
```

Base has a companion object with an apply method defined as follows:

```
object Base {
  def apply [E,S](edges:Set[Edge[E,S]],ss:MidState[S],
  aS:Set[MidState[S]],partialMode:Boolean): Base[E,S]
```

When i am trying to instantiate Base with this apply method i cannot get around an explicit type annotation for aS:

```
val aS : Set[MidState[String]] = (State("C") :: Nil).toSet
val base = Base(edges,State("A"),aS,partialMode = true)
```

If i erase the explicit type annotation for *aS*, *aS* is of type *Set[State[S]]* and not *Set[MidState[S]]* which it needs to be for the apply method. Is there any better solution to avoid this explicit type annotation despite inserting *(State("C") :: Nil).toSet* directly into the apply method?

Comment: The problem here is that a `Set[State[S]]` is not a `Set[MidState[S]]` because `Set` is invariant, so unless you force it to be on the conversion from `List` (which the type annotation does), the only other thing I can think of is an implicit conversion, which isn't great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you could do is to remove all the `:: Nil` and `.toSet` and `: ...` noise:

```
val aS = Set[MidState[String]](State("C"))
```

This is actually quite common: for example, it frequently occurs as the first argument in `fold`s, where one has to explicitly write `Set[Int]()` or `Set.empty[Int]` in order to get the types right.

If this is still too noisy, just add appropriate factory methods to `MidState`:

```
object MidState {
  def apply[S](s: S): MidState[S] = State(s)
}
```

and then invoke the factory method that constructs the right type of object right away:

```
val bS = Set(MidState("C"))
```

Comment: I like the idea of adding apply-methods to MidState. However, what do you think about holding the State generically? Adding a generic parameter to Base so it gets [S,E,ST <: MidState[S]].

Comment: @TilmanZuckmantel Adding a generic parameter to prove what? Which property would this type parameter keep track of? I don't think anything of it currently, because I don't know what exactly you're doing. Looks like some kind of graph or finite state machine, that's about all I see so far.

Comment: I am trying to model all kinds of automatons just for practising reasons alongside some theoretical lectures. The names i used here are changed because I thought they would be too long. What i am trying to do is to introduce a FailureState alongside States. Therefore i added  MidState as an interface for both. However this leads to the problem with the explicit type annotation. Holding the type of State generically would prove that the automaton has no FailureState or that it does.

Comment: @TilmanZuckmantel Well, you can certainly try it, why not... I can't really give any advice on that, because *"practicing reasons"* and *"theoretical lectures"* are not real natural forces, they don't automatically bend your code into a particular shape - you can build *anything* for practice, and it will "work" as long as you are willing to loosen your criteria for "work". It can still be *interesting*, but this entirely depends on what you subjectively find interesting.

Comment: Of course the primary aim here is to provide a simple interface for the user. By that i mean to provide the instantiation of Base as easy as possible while still remaining a wellformed base to add further operations to Base. Thats what i mean by "work".

Comment: @TilmanZuckmantel If "simple interface" is your *only* constraint, you automatically end up with Python. Type systems are not about making constructor invocations shorter. They are about proving things, enforcing invariants, and generally making insane/invalid states & structures unrepresentable. I'd suggest not to worry about the interface details too much until you get the core functionality right. As long as it does something useful, you can always wrap it into a neater DSL later, even if it's written in Java or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Andrey Tyukin introduced a solution by adding factory-methods to the MidState class which works fine. However, I solved the issue by adding a type-restriction to the apply-method ,so the signature changed from:

```
object Base {
  def apply [E,S](edges:Set[Edge[E,S]],ss:MidState[S],
  aS:Set[MidState[S]],partialMode:Boolean): Base[E,S]
```

to:

```
object Base {
  def apply [E,S](edges:Set[Edge[E,S]],ss:MidState[S],
  aS:Set[_ <: MidState[S]],partialMode:Boolean): Base[E,S]
```

Now we can pass any Set *aS* which contains elements that are subtypes of *MidState*, which is exactly what I was looking for.